# wpf MenuItem dropdown background color

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, menuitem

I want to Change the Background Color of the Dropdown of MenuItems and I have found out that I can make it, if I Change the ControlTemplate "x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey".
 I copied the controlTemplate from [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates)
 and edit all Colors but now it says that "StaticResource MenuScrollViewer" is unknown. I added this resource also from the same site but than many other resources are missing at MenuScrollView. 
So how can I edit this template so I can Change all the Colors of "MenuItem.TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey" ?

Comment: You need to include all referenced resources.

Comment: still doesnt work. "MenuScrollButton" is missing

Comment: If "MenuScrollButton" is missing you obviously haven't include this resource, have you?

Comment: but it isnt the the page. Where can I find it?

Comment: On the same place where you did find the resource that references it.

Comment: I copied everything from this page. it must be somewhere else

Comment: UpArrow & DownArrow is also missing

Comment: Did you see answer?

Answer (score 0):

The template is in the page you linked. Or at least the English version.
Here's menuscrollbutton:

```
    <Style x:Key="MenuScrollButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Hover"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <DockPanel Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="R1" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Fill="Transparent" Width="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="B1" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Fill="Transparent" Height="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="L1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="Transparent" Width="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="T1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="Transparent" Height="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="R1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="B1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="L1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="T1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentContainer" Value="3,3,1,1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

For the whole extracted templates see:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41ad0250-d0f9-4a24-b668-35020f0cfdf9/wpf-menu-customization?forum=wpf

Comment: This Code was on my linked page. The main Problem is that MenuScrollButton is missing.

Comment: I added that and a link to a post explaining how to extract templates which looks like it includes everything.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the default templates along with all referenced resources in the `PresentationFramework.*` assemblies in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\`.

Download [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or use some other .NET decompiler to decompile them look at the BAML resources under `Resources`->`PresentationFramework.*.g.resources`->`themes`.